How to determine what is causing my node server with nginx to crash at high request rate?
We are developing a SaaS product which is an easy to use invoicing software. We are using React for the frontend app and Node (with fastify web framework and sequelize as ORM) for developing a RESTful API service. For the Database we are using PostgreSQL. We are following a multi-tenant Database architecture, where every tenant will have a separate database. We want to develop the RESTful API server so that it can handle around 500 requests per second. Each request to the REST API will give around 2.1 requests to Postgres.
To make sure that we have enough connections to handle requests from multiple users, we are increasing the max_connections in PG to around 2000.
We are using nginx as a reverse proxy to handle requests to our REStful APIs.
To test if the server is able to handle the load we want, I developed a script. This script simulates requests to the server from multiple users. I am using the following logic (I have selected the 9 most used endpoints for this)

Start with 375 unique users
Send requests to each of the 9 endpoints from every user in 5 seconds (5 seconds for each endpoint. So total 3759 requests in 45 seconds) - So for 375 users it will be 3759/45 RPS = 75 RPS
Increase this by 125 users every time. So after 45 seconds, it will send 500*9 requests in 45 seconds = 100 RPS
Do this till we get an error from the server.

(NOTE: We are running everything [RESTful APIs, PG, script for sending requests] on a single VM. The VM has 7 cores and 14 GB RAM)
This is the relevant part of the script
      for (
        let numUsers = usersStart;
        numUsers <= usersEnd && failed === false;
        numUsers += usersGap
      ) {
        const totalRequests = userList.length * requestsFromEachUser;
        const waitTime = (userRequestInterval * 1e3) / numUsers;

        console.log(
          `>>> Sending ${totalRequests} requests from ${userList.length} users where each user will send ${requestsFromEachUser} requests`
        );

        const queueStartTime = Date.now();
        let cumulativeWaitTime = waitTime;

        // Each user in the group will send request 4 times in 20 seconds
        for (
          let requestNum = 0;
          requestNum < requestsFromEachUser;
          ++requestNum
        ) {
          for (let i = 0; i < userList.length && failed === false; ++i) {
            requests.push(
              sendRequest(userList[i], urls[requestNum], b, numUsers)
            );

            if (cumulativeWaitTime > MIN_WAIT_TIME) {
              await new Promise((resolve) =>
                setTimeout(resolve, cumulativeWaitTime)
              );
              cumulativeWaitTime = waitTime;
            } else {
              cumulativeWaitTime += waitTime;
            }
          }
        }

        const queueEndTime = Date.now();

        const queueExecutionTime = (queueEndTime - queueStartTime) / 1e3;
        const rps = totalRequests / queueExecutionTime;

        if (failed === false) {
          console.log(
            `>>> Sent ${totalRequests} requests from ${userList.length} users in ${queueExecutionTime} seconds with RPS = ${rps} (expected RPS = ${userList.length / userRequestInterval})`
          );
        }

        selectRandomUsers(userList, DBs, usersGap);
      }


The error I am getting on sending the request directly to the backend is ECONNRESET. And the speed I am getting is around 280 requests/second.
This speed decreases when I use nginx to ~225 requests/second.
When testing instead using a single db, (instead of a separate db for each tenant) – speed increases somewhat, but only to around 360 requests/second
This is the nginx configuration I am using
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 30000;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    log_format  main_ext  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                      '"$host" sn="$server_name" '
                      'rt=$request_time '
                      'ua="$upstream_addr" us="$upstream_status" '
                      'ut="$upstream_response_time" ul="$upstream_response_length" '
                      'cs=$upstream_cache_status' ;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main_ext;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

I have the following questions:

Is the approach we are following to ensure that we are able to handle multiple connections to DB correct? (i.e. by increasing max_connections). If yes, what are the limitations of this and is there a better approach? If not, what are the possible solutions?
Why am I getting an ECONNRESET error?
Why do the speed reduce when using nginx?
How to determine what is causing the server to fail?

I tried to check the logs for the RESTful API, but it seems like the request does not even reach it. I also tried to look at the nginx logs, but it does not give any information about the error.

What exactly is going to crash? It's unclear for me. PS you might want to adjust formatting of the config file in your post

Hi @paladin
Thanks for pointing out the formatting issue. Resolved.
Nothing crashes. When conducting the test using the script above, I get an error (ECONNRESET) from the server side. Checking the logs, it seems that the request never reaches the code or it reaches but at least, no error message is shown in the logs. Is it possible for the server to reject or close the connection abruptly when the load is high? Or, if you suspect that the request reached the code, can you suggest how I can confirm this? is there something wrong in nginx config? (I am new to nginx, so any help would be great)

Socket connections are handled by the OS, it might be possible that there is a limit for open connections.

How many Cores does the Nginx Server have? Are you running it from "VM runs everything... 7cores 14Gb_Ram"?

Hi @paladin, Thanks. How can I confirm if this is the problem?

Hi @bellasys, everything is running on the same VM for testing purposes. So nginx, RESTful API service and Postgres all are in the same VM. Even the code that I am using to test is run on the same VM.

Performance tuning is interesting but all the more so given that "everything" from Nginx, API, DB and test script is sourced on the same Server. At least some clues are in your answer - and you have provided some insight by testing multi-tenant DB vs. single and seen significant improvement there.
Quick checkup:
worker_connections 30000 is too many. Absolute Maximum would be worker_rlimit_nofile / worker_processes. Theoretical maximum may vary depending on a great number of things, but you should not need to configure more than 4096.
Since worker_processes auto; yields a maximum of 7 according to your cores, go ahead and hard code worker_processes 5; This will yield a maximum of 4096 * 5 worker_connections (this number is still 10x the 2000 Postgres)  and it will in theory free up CPU to dedicate to other tasks. Nginx is pretty smart and will focus connection tasks onto fewer cores, and leave at least 1 core for Nginx internal tasks other than connection requests... If it looks like this mod yields significant results but small like +15-25%, you may consider
actually tuning to only 4 worker_processes, and even more than this tuning all software to use CPU Affinity if possible. CPU Affinity is a feature of Nginx, but by itself may not be enough unless PG, Python, etc. can play nice.
If SSL is involved you can free up memory by invoking ssl_buffer_size 4k; vs. the Nginx default of 16k. and also IMO you only need TLSv1.2 as it will select v1.3 if the client can handle it, and nice clients don't need to insist on v1.1. The inclusion of SSL would very much explain why 9 DB tenants yield 225 but 1 DB yields 360. I'm not saying to drop it... I'm saying tune it up, and offering this as a partial explanation why introducing Nginx causes overhead. This is about connection management, not just throughput, particularly where you incrementally introduce new "Clients" throughout the test which must handshake unless the connection is reused.
We are not seeing your server{...} conf details or upstream {...} which has details of keepalive etc. Obviously managing Keepalive (number of proxy connections) is important and some tuning needs to come into play here.
There are many other factors but try a quick test with the current feedback and consider providing a few more relevant details of your config.
Keep in mind that "Requests per second" do not always equal "Transactions per second". Begin categorizing results by differentiating how many Requests are handled vs. how many requests or "transactions" meaning successful use-case requests are completed. I am pretty sure you will get to the point in which understanding this is critical to identify where the time is spent, and therefore where you need to further tune the system.
